# Looping through data frames and plotting graphs

Tags: r, loops, ggplot2

I'm working in RStudio, trying to produce some simple graphs and correlations. This is probably a super simple fix but I can't seem to loop through my files and produce plots. See below for files, loop, and sample data frame

```
> ls()
 [1] "let-7b-5p"     "let_7a_5p"     "miR_125b_5p"   "miR_16_5p"    "miR_182_5p"    "miR_21_5p"    "miR_30e_5p"    "miR_320c_2_3p" "miR_92a_1_3p"  "miR_92b_3p"
[10]  "rRNA-45S"      "tRNA_3p_1"    "tRNA_5p_2"    
> files <- ls()
> for(i in files){
+   plt <- ggplot(`i`, aes_string(x="Five", y = "Three")) +
+       geom_point(shape=16) +
+       geom_smooth(method=lm) 
+   print(plt)
+   pearson <- cor.test(`i`$Five, `i`[, "Three"], method = "pearson", conf.level = 0.95)
+   print(pearson)
+ }
Error: `data` must be a data frame, or other object coercible by `fortify()`, not a character vector
> print(`let-7b-5p`)
       Five        Three       One
A      14.06       13.14       13.62
B      14.45       14.64       14.21
C       7.84       10.23        8.05
D      12.84       13.13       13.07
E      16.55       15.97       16.01
F      12.92       12.02       12.37
```

I understand that it's seeing "files" as a character vector, but I'm not sure why that's a problem when passed to the loop.

Comment: You want to use `ls()`, which is a `character` vector with object names, to make your charts? If so, you have yo parse your ls() object into `eval` and `parse`. e.g. with the first object: `eval(parse(text = ls()[1]))`

Comment: I don't need to use ls(), but I've already imported my files (with a separate loop) and I need a way to list them to pass to the graphing loop.

Comment: In your example, `files` is `ls()`. Do `class(files[1])` for example and check what it returns you. "let-7b-5p" is different from ` `let-7b-5p` `

Answer (score 1):

Passing a string as a character vector when a function (`ggplot` here) wants a `data.frame` won't work in the loop for the same reason it won't work out of the loop...R doesn't know to retrieve the object given the name from the global environment.

I would suggest (similar to @patL's comment) retrieving the object and then running the loop:

```
for(i in files){
  dat <- get(i) # new line
  plt <- ggplot(dat, aes_string(x="Five", y = "Three")) + 
  ...
}
```

It should be noted that `ls()` will return a character vector of all objects in the environment, regardless of their class, so if you have anything else defined, you may run into issues there. From the looks of it you may be able to use the `pattern` argument to `ls()` to ensure you at least return a vector of object names matching specific patterns.

Comment: Adding get(i) did the trick, I now understand the error. Thanks!